# How to I compare values using XPath expressions in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Example XML element called book:

```
<book>
<Title> Mocking Bird </Title>
<Year> 1960 </Year>
<Genres>
<Genre> Novel </Genre>
</Genres>
</book>
```

I am trying to show all the books and the year they were published where the genre is 'novel'. Here is my code:

```
result = stmt.executeQuery("
SELECT a.book.extract('/Book/Title | /Book/Year').getStringval()
FROM BooksDB a
WHERE a.book.extract('Book/Genres/Genre').getStringVal() = ' Novel '");
```

Then I display the results to the console:

```
while(result.next()) System.out.println(result.getString(1));
```

The program runs successfully and the XPath expression is "valid" but not logically correct as it does not return any values. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking about Java XPath or XML functions querying XML saved in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath : `/book/Genres/Genre[normalize-space(text())='Novel']`